# problem with presentModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad

If my iPad is in Landscape mode and presentModalViewController is called the view automatically turns into portrait mode. Any solutions?

```
UIViewController * start = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
start.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
start.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:start animated:YES];
```

In SecondView I've already added:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return YES;
}
```

Comment: this has happened to me too - i haven't figured it out yet, so hopefully someone responds :)

Comment: The Solution is very easy: Go into Interface Builder and connect your ViewController correctly with your class. That worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your sample code is creating UIViewController instead of your actual derived class.  In other words instead you should be creating your controller like this:

```
SecondViewController *start = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
```

I'm assuming your view controller class is called "SecondViewController" because you were loading a nib by a similar name.

If you don't provide the right instance there is no way your delegate methods can be called.

Answer (score 1):

your UIViewController 'start' must override to let it appear in right orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;//UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

I got this problam just now. And I solve it by this way.
Hope this can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else going on because defining in IB doesn't work for me either. Is the original OP using a splitViewController?